# I received this error when attempting to install CP in Joomla 2.5.3

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I received this error when attempting to install CP in Joomla 2.5.3

"Another menu item with the same parent has this alias
Error building Admin Menus"

I did have a previous install problem... I tried to install in incompatible version. I uninstalled all the items and have attempted re-installs with the correct version but Custom Properties will not appear in the Components menu.

What happened? How can I fix this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say what happened. Anyway, according to the error message, there are issues with menu items.
I'd check the DB table #__menu to see if there are leftovers of the botched Custom Properties installation.